# Get an email alert when azure web sites scale up or down

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a site deployed to azure web sites. This using the built in scaling feature.

I would like to get an email alert when the website scales? How can this be achieved?

I cannot see this in the UI anywhere - is this because its not supported (yet!)?

Has anyone encountered anything similar?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this figured out.

It appears that you can do this via the web hosting plan of the azure web site. Alerts can be set up when a scale actions up or down succeeds or fails.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can setup alerts for when your website scales, but you can set alerts for when your site reaches certain CPU quotas, and can set those CPU quotas to be the same quotas that your site autoscales at.  You can set the alerts from the Monitor tab for your site on the Azure Portal

Here's an example of someone using a similar setup to monitor their site:
http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/09/10-things-i-learned-about-rapidly.html